# Unable to generate a custom path in ASP.NET MVC Master Pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view, master-pages

I am working in an ASP.NET MasterPage and am having trouble with `<link href="..." />`.

I am trying to substitute in a stylesheet with a specific name:

```
<link href="/Content/Styles/<%=Model.Style%>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Unfortunately, this creates the HTML output:

```
<link href="/Content/Styles/&lt;%=Model.Style%>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Which is clearly not what was intended.

If I put the same code in a View placeholder, it works perfectly.  This is not a good solution though as I have many pages where I just want it to do the same thing.

It looks like it's trying to automatically correct the URL - is there a way to switch this off?

---

### Edit 1:

I have fixed this temporarily using:

```
<link href=<%=String.Format("\"/Content/Styles/{0}.css\"", Model.Style)%> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the links in your question and in the solution posted thus far will fail if your site is deployed in a virtual folder. Instead, do:

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Styles/" + Model.Style + ".css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This (1) fixes the problem in your question, and (2) allows your site to work in a virtual folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<link href="/Content/Styles/<%= "" + Model.Style%>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Ugly but works.